# How should I modify my filter coefficients for the filter to be unaltered, when I change my sample rate

Tags: filters, filter-design, finite-impulse-response, resampling, multirate

I am guessing this is a commonly encountered problem, but I am lost on how to really solve it.

I have FIR filter coefficients that are used to match the frequency response of data sampled at 3 kHz. I have 12 coefficients, which I would like to implement as a filter for data being sampled at 48 kHz, but I understand, I can't directly do this.

So far, I've tried this (MATLAB):

1. Find roots of the 12 order polynomial (which are the zeros).
2. Find the magnitude and angle of the zeros.
3. Scale the magnitude(m) and angle(phi) by a factor of 3 kHz / 48 kHz.
4. Construct new zeros by multiplying m .* exp(phi);
5. Find the polynomial whose roots are the new zeros using poly.
6. Coefficients of the new polynomial are the new filter?

However, I am not sure how sound this logic really is, or if there's something wrong here entirely. I also think I'm losing a lot of information to resolution.

Any pointers on how to go about this would be really helpful!

Comment: you can interpolate the existing filter coefficients according to the new sampling rate.

Comment: Thanks! Just noticed the comment. I used the resample function in matlab to interpolate up by a factor of 16... and it seems to work and there's a lot of ripple, but the filter is there, and intact... Just wondering: does this affect the stability of the filter in any way?

Comment: it won't affect the stability of FIR filters.

Comment: The ripple will depend to some degree on the interpolation method used.